# Redis not Installing on MacOS

Tags: macos, redis

[image]Any Solutions to the above problem

Got the same error while installing mongo but not able to remember what i did

Answer (score 0):

run `brew doctor`

then run `git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master`

Comment: Please provide some more context about what these steps are doing.